# Terraform: How to fix azurerm_cosmosdb_account creation times out

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Creating a Cosmos DB via Terraform with Replicate data globally enabled times out after one hour with a status code:

StatusCode=202 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded

Are there any solutions so Terraform can complete successfully?

We tried adding the timeout operation to the Terraform code, however it is not supported

Terraform code that is timing out:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = "${local.name}"
  location = "${var.azure_location}"
  tags     = "${var.tags}"
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {
  name                = "${local.name}"
  location            = "${var.azure_location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name}"
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "GlobalDocumentDB"
  tags                = "${var.tags}"

  enable_automatic_failover = false

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level = "Session"
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = "${var.failover_azure_location}"
    failover_priority = 1
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = "${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location}"
    failover_priority = 0
  }
}
```

I'd expect that Terraform would complete successfully since the Cosmos DB is created post the Terraform timeout without error.

Comment: according to documentation, the "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" has section: "timeouts".  You say you have tried to use this section, could you show the code with this section?

Answer (score 0):

For those that come here and looking for a working example.

- Terraform v1.5.5
- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v3.77.0
- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.5.1

```
# export TL_LOG=DEBUG
# random string - only aplpha numeric
resource "random_string" "suffix" {
  length  = 6
  special = false
  numeric = false
  upper   = false
}

locals {
  name                  = "cosmosdbtest${random_string.suffix.result}"
  azure_location        = "westeurope"
  azure_backup_location = "northeurope"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = "rg-cosmosdb-test"
  location = local.azure_location
  tags     = { "random" : "tag" }
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {
  name                = local.name
  location            = local.azure_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "GlobalDocumentDB"
  tags                = { "random" : "tag" }

  enable_automatic_failover = false

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level = "Session"
  }

  geo_location {
    # location that is not westeurope
    location          = local.azure_backup_location
    failover_priority = 1
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }
}

output "name" {
  value = random_string.suffix.result
}
```